# How to reorder a factor based on a subset (facets) of another variable, using forcats?

Tags: r, forcats

`forcats` [vignette](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/articles/forcats.html) states that

> The goal of the forcats package is to provide a suite of useful tools
>   that solve common problems with factors

And indeed one of the tools is to reorder factors by another variable, which is a very common use case in plotting data. I was trying to use `forcats` to accomplish this, but in the case of a faceted plot. That is, I want to reorder a factor by other variable, but using only a subset of the data. Here's a reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut, clarity) %>% 
    summarise(value = mean(table, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = clarity, y = value, color = clarity)) + 
    geom_segment(aes(xend = clarity, y = min(value), yend = value), 
                 size = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
    geom_point(size = 3) + 
    facet_grid(rows = "cut", scales = "free") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This code produces the plot close to what I want:

[image]

But I want the clarity axis to be sorted by value, so I can quickly spot which clarity has the highest value. But then each facet would imply a different order. So I'd like to choose to order the plot by the values within a specific facet.

The straightforward use of `forcats`, of course, does not work in this case, 'cause it would reorder the factor based on all the values, and not only the values of a specific facet. Let's do it:

```
# Inserting this line right before the ggplot call
mutate(clarity = forcats::fct_reorder(clarity, value)) %>%
```

It then produces this plot. [image]

Of course, it reordered the factor based on the whole data, but what if I want the plot ordered by the values of the "Ideal" cut?, How can I do this with `forcats`?

My current solution would be as follows:

```
ggdf <- ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut, clarity) %>% 
    summarise(value = mean(table, na.rm = TRUE))

# The trick would be to create an auxiliary factor using only
# the subset of the data I want, and then use the levels
# to reorder the factor in the entire dataset.
#
# Note that I use good-old reorder, and not the forcats version
# which I could have, but better this way to emphasize that
# so far I haven't found the advantage of using forcats 
reordered_factor <- reorder(ggdf$clarity[ggdf$cut == "Ideal"], 
                            ggdf$value[ggdf$cut == "Ideal"])

ggdf$clarity <- factor(ggdf$clarity, levels = levels(reordered_factor))

ggdf %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = clarity, y = value, color = clarity)) + 
    geom_segment(aes(xend = clarity, y = min(value), yend = value), 
                 size = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
    geom_point(size = 3) + 
    facet_grid(rows = "cut", scales = "free") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Which produces what I want.

[image]

But I wonder if there is a more elegant/clever way to do it using `forcats`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to reorder `clarity` by the values of a particular facet you have to tell `forcats::fct_reorder()` to do so, e.g.,

```
mutate(clarity = forcats::fct_reorder(
    clarity, filter(., cut == "Ideal") %>% pull(value)))
```

which uses only the values for the "Ideal" facet for reordering.

Thus,

```
ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, clarity) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(table, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(clarity = forcats::fct_reorder(
    clarity, filter(., cut == "Ideal") %>% pull(value))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = clarity, y = value, color = clarity)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = clarity, y = min(value), yend = value), 
               size = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  facet_grid(rows = "cut", scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

creates

[image]

as requested.

Comment: if this does not work first go, make sure your facet variable is the first variable in the `group_by` function.